# No permitir acceso a defaultUrl en archivo web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Tengo una aplicación web que tiene como `loginUrl="Index.aspx"` y como `defaultUrl="list.aspx"`.

Esto funciona bien, porque una vez que tengo el `Index.aspx` y espero que el usuario se identifique, logro obtener la página `list.aspx`.

El problema es que si pongo directamente la URL de `list.aspx`, puedo abrirlo sin tener que pasar por `Index.aspx`.

¿Cómo puedo bloquear el acceso y que solamente una vez de haber pasado por `Index.aspx` la página `list.aspx` sea afichada?

Muchas gracias de ante mano.

Aqui esta parte de mi `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Index.aspx"
             slidingExpiration="true"
             defaultUrl="list.aspx"
             timeout="600" name=".Auth"
             protection="All"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Lograste resolverlo? Porque tengo el mismo problema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes agregar una autorización en el `Web.config` con el siguiente comando:

```
<system.web>

<authentication mode="Forms">
</authentication>

<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/> <!--acá denegas el acceso a los usuarios anónimos-->
</authorization>

</system.web>
```

Te dejo este link donde puedes ver más info al respecto:
[Setting authorization](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config)

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he probado y era exactamente lo que necesitaba.